# How do you identify a Relic?

Tags: magic-items, cairn

There's nothing in the rulebook about how to identify what a Relic does, nor its recharge condition.

Does a PC just learn these things upon acquisition of the item?

Do they need to experiment with it by using it? Some of the recharge conditions are fairly... unlikely, if you're just experimenting.

Do they need some kind of save to figure it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is intentionally left vague in the rules, but you only save if there is a risk. With some Relics this may be the case!

However most of the time, I just tell the PCs what the thing does, provided they have time to experiment. If not, I might let them try something hastily, teasing out what might happen and asking for an appropriate save or action on their behalf.

Comment: It is awesome that we can have a developer directly respond, but is this somewhere in your rules that OP and others can reference?

Comment: Nope. It is intentionally left vague.

Comment: That’ sounds like something I’d like to read in the answer! And would like to hear about why, but that’s because we rarely get a real why!